# Wpf trigging events inside user control between elements

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a ListViewItem that has two grids. When the user clicks the first grid, it shows the second grid. But as it is a user control, I cant find it inside in code-behind.

```
<UserControl>
    <ListView>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="models:Tweet">
                <ListViewItem>
                    <Grid Name="Grid1" OnMouseLeftDown="ShowsGrid2"/>
                    <Grid Name="Grid2"/>
                </ListViewItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}">
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
</UserControl>

public void PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender)
{
    var control = (Grid)sender;
    sender.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

But I get: control = null Exception

Comment: Don't set visibility on the sender itself. You need to set your visibility on the control that you just tried casting to a (Grid). As noted by the comment @Micheal I am as well unsure what the question is as well. However, initially noticed the problem noted as above.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The listview item has the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown set to change the grid visibility. I want to imitate the twitter chat expandable textbox behavior. www.twitter.com. @IdahoSixString are you saing that I must get the grid inside the listviewitem ? How could I do that ?

Comment: IS the handler acutally "ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" ?  .... or "ShowsGrid2" ?

Comment: @GordonTrue I edited the question to be more clear. The correct is PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown hooked on listviewitem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend creating a property in your code-behind:

```
public Visibility Grid2Visibility { get; set; }
```

Then, bind the visibility of the Grid to that property, in XAML:

```
<Grid ... Visibility="{Binding Grid2Visibility}" ... />
```

Then, you can handle whatever event you want and set the visibility of Grid2 accordingly:

```
public void HandleSomeEvent(object sender, SomeArgs e)
{
    // I can collapse Grid2
    Grid2Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

    // or I can show it
    Grid2Visibility = Visibility.Visible;   
 }
```

Another option would be to use [Triggers](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-datatrigger-event-trigger/).  Here is a quick and dirty example of one button's clicking event triggering the visibility of a second button:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Button 1">
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.Target="{x:Reference Button2}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
    <Button Name="Button2" Visibility="Collapsed">Button 2</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Can you give please me a Trigger example ? Since I am using data template

Comment: Example added to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how to do the code behind.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private Visibility _gird2Visibility;
    public Visibility Grid2Visibility
    {
        get { return _gird2Visibility; }
        set
        {
            _gird2Visibility = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Grid2Visibility");
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Grid2Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    private void Grid1_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
       Grid2Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void Grid1_OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid2Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the XAML

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Name="Grid1" MouseDown="Grid1_OnMouseDown" MouseUp="Grid1_OnMouseUp" >
        <TextBlock Text="CLICK ANYWHERE WITHIN THE GRID TO SHOW SECOND GRID" />
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1"  Name="Grid2" Visibility="{Binding Grid2Visibility}" >
        <TextBlock Text="I AM VISIBLE" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I do not know your data context for your window. However, this is how i set it up in my example

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```